# What is the Asynchronous Benefit of ReadAsMultipartAsync?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

A coworker showed me some code in which they're processing an uploaded file in ASP.NET Web Api. It was something like this:

```
    Task<IEnumerable<HttpContent>> task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    return task.ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(contents =>
    {
        //Do stuff...
    }
```

What is the benefit of reading the file asynchronously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the file from the network socket is an I/O bound operation. Doing it asynchronously ensures that you are not jeopardizing worker threads on the server during this reading but you are taking advantage of an I/O Completion Port.

Answer (score 3):

It is all about freeing the thread perocessing the request by using async. Once you do that, the thread will be able to serve another request.

Also better not use `ContinueWith`, I am explaining [why](http://byterot.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/tpl-async-parallel-task-library-server-lesson-hard-way.html).

Comment: Hey I see that you're very active in the .net community - so thanks for that. However, as I understand it, reading a file is CPU-bound. If that's the case, what is the point of reading it asynchronously?

Comment: @scoarescoare, reading a file is almost certain to be io bound, **not** CPU bound

Comment: @scoarescoare It is IO-bound. Reading from network, accessing file system, reading database, reading from streams (redis, ...) is IO-bound. **Doing calculation is CPU-bound.**

Comment: @spender thanks for the clarification. Please see my comment below.

Comment: @Aliostad Yes, you are correct. My mistake as far as the terminology. I was under the assumption that reading an uploaded file from the network socket was handled by a **.NET resource** and therefore resulted in a waste of context switching. I know understand I/O Completion Ports are used by the OS to read the file from the network socket. Does that make sense/ you see why I was confused?

Comment: @scoarescoare, I've posted my comment as answer.

Comment: @Aliostad what is the reason not to use ContinueWith? The article you posted a link to does not say why not to. It says it is one of the ways to handle an exception but not why we shouldn't use it with a web api controller method.

Comment: @AranMulholland because it will not flow the context, i.e. HttpContext will be null. Now this might not be a problem but sometimes clients of your library depend on this.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronous IO takes time and hangs your code, even if it's off the disk (as opposed to the net). Switching to async IO mitigates this by letting the framework deal with your IO requests without blocking your client code.

Comment: As you recall, the question is not about how async works or the benefit of async programming. I'm curious as to why reading an uploaded file asynchronously has much benefit in ASP.NET Web API. In this case, a resource is still required to process the file.

Comment: Yes, a resource is required to process the file but your question was about reading the file from the network socket -`Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync`. It is async in order to free all threads during this reading and benefit from I/O Completion Ports. If you read it synchronously then you would be wasting resources on the server not only for processing the file but for reading it as well.

Comment: As you recall, your actual question ends ' What is the benefit of reading the file asynchronously?' Which bit did I get wrong?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for introducing me to I/O completion ports - that clears things up. Make this an answer.